# Concatenation of XML elements to generate a new element

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to XSLT and working on converting one format of XML to another. I am writing an XSL file and here I need to concatenate some elements from the XML file so that it can be put out as a new element in the new XML file that will be generated. TO elaborate, here is the code

XML file has the following elements:

```
<Type>Code</Type>
<TypeDesc>Description</TypeDesc>
<Type2Code>Code2</Type2Code>
<Type2Desc>Description2</Type2Desc>
```

New element needs to be

```
 <Text> [Description (Code) - Description2(Code2)]</Text>
```

Can anyone please suggest how I should write my XSL to get this. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such a localized and under-specified question deserves an equally *ad hoc* solution, so here you go:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
       <Text> 
            <xsl:value-of select="
                 concat(' [', /*/TypeDesc, ' (', /*/Type, ') - ', 
                              /*/Type2Desc, '(', /*/Type2Code, ')]')"/>
       </Text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<Text> [Description (Code) - Description2(Code2)]</Text>
```